# Dúvida sobre Query - Agrupar dados

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tenho uma dúvida sobre como agrupar os dados da seguinte forma.

Tenho uma tabela chamada *ALUNO_LEGADO*, conforme abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Preciso montar uma query para pegar todos os alunos que reprovaram em todas as disciplinas matriculadas em um determinado ano. Ex.: Selecionar os alunos que reprovaram em todas as disciplinas cursadas em 2015.

- Obs.: os conceitos são: A = Aprovado, R = Reprovado
- Obs. 2: Não há um número de disciplinas padrão para cada aluno, pois ele tem a livre escolha de se matricular em 1 ou mais disciplinas.

A ideia é selecionar o cara que reprovou em todas as disciplinas na qual ele esteve relacionado no ano de 2015.

---

```
create table aluno_legado
SELECT 
RA

FROM ALUNO_LEGADO

WHERE conceito = 'R'
AND ano = 2015

GROUP BY RA
```

No entanto esta query traz simplesmente RA's que tem conceito R em 2015, e não apenas os alunos que reprovaram em todas as disciplinas cursadas em 2015. Entende?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Utilizando `not exists`

Além de agrupar por `RA`, você deve negar caso o aluno tenha sido aprovado em alguma matéria.

```
select nome, ra, ano
  from aluno_legado al
 where ano = 2015
   and not exists(select 1
                    from aluno_legado e
                   where e.ra=al.ra
                     and e.ano=al.ano 
                     and e.conceito='A')
 group by ra, nome, ano
```

Veja mais detalhes nesse [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c671d/2).

Explicando: Caso o sub-select que procura por matérias em que o aluno tenha sido aprovado retorne alguma linha a cláusula `not exists` vai falhar.

### Utilizando `having`

Outra alternativa assumindo que a coluna `conceito` somente possa ter os valores `A` e `R` seria com a cláusula `having` utilizando a função `min`.

```
select nome, ra, ano
  from aluno_legado al
 where ano = 2015
 group by ra, nome, ano
having min(conceito) = 'R'
```

Veja mais detalhes neste [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c671d/1).

Explicando: como `A` é menor que `R` caso o aluno tenha sido aprovado em qualquer matéria a função `min` vai retornar `A` fazendo a comparação falhar.

Coloquei a coluna nome somente para facilitar a visualização.

Comment: Obrigado HwapX utilizei a primeira solução e deu certo !